# File emptied when command not found

Tags: external-command, ex-mode, ex-command

Given this command:

```
ex -sc '%!alfa' -cx file
```

I get this result:

```
sh: alfa: command not found
```

which is to be expected. However an unintended side effect of this is that the
file is emptied and saved.

Can this command be modified so that if the external command is not found, then
Vim bails instead of saving an empty file?

Comment: Cannot replicate on Linux/Vim7.4, the exact same command: fails (because of "alfa" which does not exist), opens a new buffer but does not save a file.  How exactly are you running it? My best try to replicate it was: `echo data > file1 ; vim -u NONE -c "ex -sc '%\!alfa' -cx file2" file1`

Comment: I actually did that from the command line.  It was mostly to highlight the fact that i'm using `-u NONE` (which is a good idea when debugging something).  In general i'm confused about what exactly you are performing just as much you are confused about what i am performing.  But you are the one with a question, can i ask you to elaborate exactly what you're running?  Is it a command-mode ex (a `:` normal-mode command)?  Or you're entering ex-mode?  Or you're running ex from the command line?

Comment: I may be wrong (this is purely from experience) but running the `ex` command in `vim` behaves differently from running the `ex` binary.  Not all systems have `ex` as a call to `vim -e`.  But now I get you.  I can replicate it with `vim -u NONE -e -sc '%!alfa' -cx file` (i believe that is the portable command, not sure if `-u NONE` is needed)

Comment: I'd argue it is a bug.  Vim does **not** figure out correctly that the buffer has not been changed.  `vim -e -scx file` works as expected but even `vim -e -sc '%!echo >/dev/null' -cx file` writes the empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`v:shell_error`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#v%3Ashell_error) to test whether the external command succeeded or failed. Typically a non-zero result means the command failed.

In that case, you can use `:q!` to exit the Ex script with the file unmodified. Or, perhaps better, use the [`:cq!`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acq) command to have Ex/Vim exit with a non-zero exit code, so your script calling Ex can also detect that something went wrong.

For example:

```
$ ex -s -c '%!alfa' -c 'if v:shell_error|cq!|endif' -c 'x' file
sh: alfa: command not found
$ echo $?
1
$ cat file
(Original contents of file.)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I am now using the shell builtin `type alfa` before the Vim call.